# Load html files in TinyMce

Tags: ajax, tinymce

I have this:

```
<textarea name="content"></textarea>
```

and in javascript code in the same aspx file I call init to tinyMce.

I have html file which is in the same folder as this aspx file. How to make it show in the tinyMce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eighter render the content of your html file into the textare directly OR
use ajax to get the file contents and set them as content of your editor.
I assume your tinymce editor is already initialized then you may set the content from the ajax response using

```
tinymce.get('my_editorid').setContent(html_content);
```