# get the html file content and send it to page in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tinymce

I want get a content of html file using C# and the pass those into cshtml view  page. is this possible to do ?

my main requirement is **load a html file into TinyMCE editor content**, which is located at another destination.

but once I explore about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014947/load-html-file-as-initial-content-in-tinymce-editor) I saw given answers like below

> You cannot give a path to the setContent function directly. What you need to do is to get the html file contents backendside and send it to your page where you insert it into your editor using the setContent method.

but I dont know how to **get the html file content and send it to page in asp.net mvc**

However I tried like below to insert html file using jquery

```
    setup: function(ed) {
    ed.on("init", function(ed) {            
        $.get("myhtml.html", function (content) { 

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);

        });

    })}
```

but this once also not working for me. any suggestion would be highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Instead of using it from the jQuery i'll suggest to create the MVC controller action with string return type and then use File.ReadAllText method of System.IO assembly to get the content of the html file.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IHtmlString TyneMice()
    {
       return new MvcHtmlString(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filename"));
    }
}
```

you can call this controller and action from jQuery.

I hope this answer helps you. If you need more detail on how to read the content from html file you can [find here](http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/code-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-string)

Comment: Whats jquery snippet use to call this function ?

Comment: you can use $get function only thing you have to use controller action instead of .html file path. As shown below

Comment: $.get("/home/TyneMice", function (content) { 

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);

        });

Comment: Can you please let me know what's the error you are getting. Also if can share code that you have written that would help me to solve your problem

Comment: This is code relevant code snippet https://dotnetfiddle.net/5OqEEH and this is the HTML file https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/KKe8k/myhtml-html-file

Comment: Did some code correction in the answer. Instead of returning string i change it to IHtmlString and wrap the file content inside MVCHtmlString. We should remember is that razor encodes everything by default, but by using MvcHtmlString in your html helpers you can tell razor that it doesn't need to encode it.